# Java - Filling multidimensional (2d) ArrayList like a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

A while ago before I got used to object object oriented programming I created a basic TicTacToe game and to create the board I used an array.

The code is a complete mess because I didn't properly understand how to use objects, but I did initialize the board correctly:

```
char[][] board = new char[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
        board[i][j] = '[]' //or something like that...don't remember exactly
    }
}
```

My question is how would you this with an ArrayList?

```
     ArrayList <ArrayList<Character>> board = new ArrayList(); // this initialization is not
    // wrong using Java 8 but for earlier versions you would need to state the type on both 
//sides of the equal sign not just the left
        for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++){
                    board.get(i).get(j).add('[]');
                }
            }
```

but that does not work.

It does not have to be exactly like this, I just generally want to understand how to handle multidimensional ArrayLists.

-thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike arrays, you can't initialize an entire ArrayList directly. You *can* specify the expected size beforehand (this helps performance when you are using very large lists, so it is a good practice to do it always).

```
int boardSize = 3;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>(boardSize);
for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    board.add(new ArrayList<Character>(boardSize));
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++){
        board.get(i).add('0');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that in your original code you had a multi-dimensional array of primitives (in this case, `char`) and all you had to do was assign a new primitive value to each slot in the array.

However what you want now is an `ArrayList` of (`ArrayList` of `Character`). When you create the `ArrayList` it is empty. In order to procede you are going to need to fill it with several (`ArrayList` of `Character`) before you can begin to start adding `Character`s themselves.

So for example,

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<Character>> board = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  board.add(new ArrayList<Character>());
}
```

Now you can start adding `Character`s to your lists:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
    board.get(i).add('A');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed it does...thank you good sir. Can't upvote yet but would if I could

Answer (score 1):

First you have to initialize the ArrayList in your first line correctly and than you have to initialize an new ArrayList in each run of your first loop:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<Character>> board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    ArrayList<Character> innerList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    board.add(innerList);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        innerList.add('[');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. Can't upvote yet but would if I could. However since I am using Java 8, your original statement saying the ArrayList is initialized incorrectly, is wrong. In java 8, you do not need the type on both sides of the equal sign, just the left.